# fill color in only visible part of layout, not in invisible part of layout

Tags: android, xml, transparency

I have one relative layout within that image view. I want to fill color in relative layout only in visible portion of layout. The portion covered by image view  in relative layout should be transparent. I need this to achieve transparency between relative layout and image view.

[image]
<sub>(source: [123rf.com](http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/denchik/denchik1204/denchik120400063/13223026-bright-grey-background-with-two-transparent-frame.jpg))</sub>

Comment: welcome to SO.If you provide some URL of image it will be helpful.

Comment: http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/denchik/denchik1204/denchik120400063/13223026-bright-grey-background-with-two-transparent-frame.jpg.   instead of white color in image. i need transparent color.

Comment: which white color you are talking about?the white border?If it is relative layout than set background to #00000000.this will set fully transparent.

Comment: yes, if set the transparent color, i will have image surrounded by transparent. if i place this whole viewgroup into another view, that transparent color is changed into the view color. i need to avoid that one.

Comment: create transparent border in between two views(two relative layout or tow linear layout, what ever).